# Are there simple rules for use of “in”, “on”, “at”, “from” and “for”?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I often get confused how to use
**in**, **on**, **at**, **from** and **for**.

Examples:

> I have a phone in/on/at my bag.
>
> Meet me at/in/on this hotel.

They sound kind of right but I'm not sure which  is correct.

Is there a simple way to remember how to use those?

Comment: I'm afraid that knowing when to use which preposition is learned through practice. Any rules are full of holes.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up Matt. Yes, that's what I also thought, but I also have to start from somewhere :) I don't want to be using wrong preposition without any initial guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *to* and *for* are usually used for an indirect object, such as:

> I gave a book *to Tom for his birthday*.

- *in* is short for *inside*, denoting a location in the *interior* of something; for example:

> I have a phone *in my bag*.

- *on* is a location resting on top of, or above, something else:

> The lamp was *on the table*.

- *at* describes being in proximity to, or coincident with, a geographic location:

> Oh no! I left the tickets *for the play at the hotel, in the envelope, on the dresser*.

Another usage of *to* is the one opposite in meaning to *from*. In this case motion between two locations (or times) is inferred, with the source being referenced by *from* and the destination by *to*:

> I moved the car *from* the garage *to* the street so we could finally patch the hole in the floor.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it, Pieter. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're most welcome. I just added a minor edit to the first example to exemplify both prepositions (*to* and *for*) leading indirect objects.