# "Arguments in each topic" or "arguments on each topic"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is the right way to express the following?

> You have to present your arguments **in** each topic.
>
> You have to present your arguments **on** each topic.

Or maybe there is yet another preposition to use?

Comment: arguments for each topic.  arguments about each topic. arguments over each topic.

Answer (score 6):

### A Possible Source of Confusion:

1. It is understandable that this choice between prepositions would be confusing--especially to a non-native English speaker. Without regard to the object of the preposition, the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arguments+in%2C+arguments+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carguments%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carguments%20on%3B%2Cc0) tends to favor the expression *arguments in* significantly over *arguments on*:

[image]

But the [corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20each%20topic%2Con%20each%20topic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20each%20topic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20each%20topic%3B%2Cc0) also tends to favor the expression *on each topic* significantly over *in each topic*:

[image]

---

### The Native Sense of Connection:

2. The answer to this related [ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125222/are-there-simple-rules-for-use-of-in-on-at-from-and-for) offers some simple principles to understand the semantic differences between prepositions. Prepositions **connect** discrete semantic units into a meaningful phrase, and it seems that native speakers of English prefer to connect *arguments* to *topic* with the preposition *[on](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22arguments%20on%20each%20topic%22)*, rather than with the preposition *[in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22arguments%20in%20each%20topic%22)*.

---

### The Connotations of Other Prepositions:

3. The prepositions *for*, *about* and *over* might also be used to connect *topic* and *argument*, but the connotations of those expressions would tend to shift the focus away from the *rational presentation of information*, and toward *the interaction of opposing views*:

> - *arguments **on** each topic*--connotes the rational arrangement of premises and    conclusions
> - *arguments **for** each topic*--connotes the advocacy of conclusions ( with the implication of a preconceived bias)
> - *arguments **about** each topic*--connotes the back and forth exchange between opposing views (with the implication of some emotional
>     content)
> - *arguments **over** each topic*--connotes the back and forth exchange between opposing views (with the implication of more emotional content)

When ***on*** connects *argument* and *topic* it tends to connote a particular definition of *[argument](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/argument)*:

> 2 A reason or set of reasons given in support of an idea, action or
>   theory:
>
> *ODO*

When ***for***, ***about*** and ***over*** connect **argument** and *topic* they tend to move progressively  toward a different definition of *[argument](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/argument)*:

> 1 An exchange of diverging or opposite views, typically a heated or
>   angry one:
>
> *ODO*

---

### The Verb *Present*:

4. The [relationship](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=present%20on%20a%20topic%2Cpresent%20in%20a%20topic&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpresent%20on%20a%20topic%3B%2Cc0) between the verb *present* and the noun *topic* also tends to reinforce the choice of *[on](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22present%20on%20each%20topic%22)* over *[in](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22present%20in%20each%20topic%22)*. Two examples will suffice to demonstrate how the two prepositions connect *present* and *topic*:

> In case the information ***we present on each topic*** is not detailed
>   enough for your purposes, we concluded just about every chapter with a
>   resource section...
>   *[The College Woman's Handbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=wy5RJtHJPqQC&pg=PP14&dq=%22present%20on%20each%20topic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QW5CVcrhJcm6ggSNk4HACg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22present%20on%20each%20topic%22&f=false)*, by Rachel Dobkin and Shana Sippy.
>
> Finally, the implication for explanations of drug mechanisms and new
>   drug design ***is present in each topic*** discussed.
>   *[Chimie Pure Et Appliquée](https://books.google.com/books?id=uPIqAQAAMAAJ&q=%22present%20in%20each%20topic%22&dq=%22present%20in%20each%20topic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2G1CVbGILoOVNoDHgPAM&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ)*
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

In the first example the preposition *on* connects *topic* and *[present](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/present#present-2)* in the fashion of the OP:

> verb ...
>
> 1.2 Show or offer (something) for others to scrutinize or consider:
>
> *ODO*

In the second example, the preposition *in* connects *topic* and *[present](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/present#present)* in a completely different manner:

> adjective ...
>
> 1.1 Existing or occurring in a place or thing:
>
> *ODO*

---

### An Example:

5. The [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/closing-as-off-topic) designations of StackExchange follows the native understanding of the connection between *topics* and *presenting arguments*:

> To be effective, *we present arguments **on** topic*.

---

### Conclusion:

Although it is not the only acceptable preposition, ***on*** seems to be the preferable choice for the *prima facia* meaning of the sentence. Of course, it is quite possible that the author intends to convey a subtle distinction, which might affect the choice according to the principles outlined above.

Comment: Thansk a lot for this complete answere - really helped me. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

Google Books (not vanilla Google) tells you the following on your core constructs:

["arguments **on** each topic"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22arguments%20on%20each%20topic%22)
About 68 results

["arguments **about** each topic"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22arguments%20about%20each%20topic%22)
6 results

["arguments **in** each topic"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your%20arguments%20ON%20each%20topic%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22arguments%20in%20each%20topic%22)
8 results

"On" is the most recommended (together with "for," suggested by GEdgar) but they are all correct English, IMO.